# php ветвление процессов

Tags: php

как на php разветвить процесс так чтобы родительский процесс не дожидался завершения дочерних. Тестирую на винде, запускаю рабочий на убунту.
Для примера

```
echo '<div>2 процесса</div>';
sleep(50);
```

так чтобы сервер отдал `<div>2 процесса</div>` моментально, а другой процесс выполнял `sleep(50);`
В дальнейшем в диве будет прогресс бар и эта страница будет общаться со скриптом `sleep(50);` через вебсокеты и конечно же будет выполняться не 50 секунд, а полчаса или даже час

Comment: можно конечно попробовать запустить в php консольную команду и stdout выкинуть в пустоту, чтобы php не дожидался ответа, но хочется более красивое решение

Comment: По-моему в этом случае можно обойтись без потоков.  Я в подобной задаче делал так: принимал запрос, валидировал, отдавал ответ клиенту с закрытием соединения и запускал вычисления. Вычисления у меня проходили по нескольким статусам - эти статусы возвращались при повторном вызове скрипта.

Comment: " отдавал ответ клиенту с закрытием соединения и запускал вычисления" - меня как раз это и интересует + надо учесть что передаются данные из $_POST и самое главное из $_FILES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант скрипта, который по запросу клиента запускает, продолжительные по времени, вычисления и возвращает ответ не дожидаясь их окончания.**

При запросе проверяется текущее состояние вычислений. Если, в рамках текущей сессии, вычислений еще не было, то клиенту возращается ответ с информацией о начале таких вычислений, соединение закрывается и вычисления начинают выполняться.

После выполнения вычислений состояние изменяется на выполненное.

На все запросы, которые приходят во время выполнения вычислений и после их завершения - возвращается информация о их текущем состоянии.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
    $curStatus = "started";
    $_SESSION['status'] = false;
} elseif (!$_SESSION['status']) {
    $curStatus = "In progress... " . (time() - $_SESSION['started']) . "secs";
} else {
    $curStatus = "finished";
}
if ($curStatus == "started") {
    $_SESSION['started'] = time();

    // Возвращаем ответ и закрываем соединение клиенту -->
    @ob_clean();
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    session_write_close(); // закрыть сессию, чтобы снять с нее блокировку и не блочить выполнение скриптов, также использующих ее
    //
    // Этот блок нужен только для того, чтобы не вызывался php_session_send_cookie(),
    // во время будущего второго вызова ф-ии session_start(),
    // т.к. заголовки уже были отправлены во время ее первого вызова  --->
    //
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', false);
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', false);
    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
    ini_set('session.cache_limiter', null);
    // <---
    echo $curStatus;
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
    @ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
    fastcgi_finish_request(); // <-- Если используется SAPI FPM
    // <---

    // Начинаем выполнение продолжительных вычислений --->
    sleep(60);
    // <---
    session_start(); // открыть снова сессию и записать в нее "результат вычислений"
    $_SESSION['status'] = true;
} else {
    echo $curStatus;
}
```

Для сохранения состояния вычислений в примере я использовал сессию, поэтому приходится ее освобождать(закрывать) на время вычисления, а после вычислений - открывать снова для записи в нее.

Comment: вообще все ответы достойны внимания. Сделал как здесь, правда ответ хотелось увидеть проще типа 
echo '<div>2 процесса</div>';
session_write_close();
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(50);
а вот получает клиент информацию из вебсокетов

Comment: мой товарищ рекомендует использовать $process = proc_open('my-command –inputargument1 a', $descriptorspec, $pipes); для распараллеливания - стремная задача распаралеливать то что уже распаралелено на клиентов

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, если я правильно понял, то тебе можно попробовать потоки: [Потоки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.thread.php)

Comment: выложите пожалуйста простой пример с echo и sleep или где похожая картина

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Ветвить процесс не надо. Унесите слип в отдельное приложение. В обработчике запуска инициируйте запуск, отвечайте клиенту `<div>2 процесса</div>` и дело сделано.

Как инициировать запуск обработчика со слипом в отдельном приложении? Надо отправить приложению сообщение, а оно тем временем должно внимательно слушать и получив сообщение стартовать ваш слип.

Можно написать демона на php и отправить ему сообщение в сокет, можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями (например gearman), можно даже просто записать задачу на запуск в файл и по крону читать его скриптом на php, и если там новая задача, то запускать слип.

Вот симпатичная [статья про gearman](https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+gearman+%D0%B8+php), в которой объясняется схема работы.