# Как сделать web приложение с независимым беком?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, веб-программирование, apache

Как создать web приложение, что бы можно было запустить скрипт, который бы не прекращал своё выполнение, ибо если делать через ajax, то приходится ждать выполнение скрипта, а мне бы хотелось запустить скрипт и ajax-ом проверять ход его работы.
Возможно ли такое? Если да, то куда читать?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону [long polling](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling)

Comment: @LevShportak вопрос же про php + js. Никак не про nodejs

Comment: аяксом тоже можно, что у Вас не получается?

Comment: аяксом я и работаю. Но мне его "мало" что ли. Например есть задачи, которые долго выполняются. Из за ограничения сервера мне приходится разбивать задачу на подзадачи и выплнять их последовательно при помощи аякса. Это тратит время. Мне бы хотелось что бы код был не разбит на подзапросы аякса, а что бы работал, а я мог на фронте просто смотреть его логи, этапы и т.д.
Да и бывает что при циклическом аяксе возникает ошибка пустой переменной(которая возвращается с сервера), хотя она заполнена и в ней есть данные, но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: вебсокеты, на `php` тоже их можно сделать

Comment: я не понимаю что мешает аяксом запустить долгую задачу в фоновом режиме, сразу же ответить мол задача запущена. и запросом к другому эндпоинту смотреть что происходит

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Потому что через некоторое время приходит ошибка 500, тип долго

Comment: @АлексейЩербаков Вы не внимательно прочитали мое сообщение, ответить клиенту надо сразу после запуска задачи, мол задача запущена. а не ждать окончания

Comment: посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009096/327441) ответ. В нем есть живой пример для вашего случая.

Comment: @Jigius я сначала не понял, а потом кааааак понял. Очень интересный пример. Одно только, если вычисления больше n времени - сервак кладёт процесс и говорит 500 ощибка, досвидааанья. Я знаю что можно увеличивать время на сервере, но запросы бывают разные, а бесконечность не поставишь в настройках сервера :)

Comment: @АлексейЩербаков, ```...сервак кладёт процесс и говорит 500 ощибка``` . На виртуальном хостинге могут быть наложены ограничения на время выполнения запущенных процессов, но это как правило _часы_(например, у бегет'а - 10часов). Ошибки 500 не должно быть, т.к. ответ отдается практически сразу, без задержки.