# Как продолжить выполнять PHP-скрипт после закрытия браузера?

Tags: php

PHP-скрипт запускается через адресную строку браузера. Как сделать скрипт работающим до конца цикла (более миллиона итераций) при закрытом браузере?

Comment: Через планировщик, Cron.

Comment: Посмотрите [вот этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215188/9271527).

Comment: Какое отношение имеет браузер к серверу? Правильно, никакого!

Comment: Если закрыть вкладку браузера, то у меня скрипт прекращает выполняться. Хоть в браузер ничего не выводится.

Comment: @Frontender какую-то фантастику вы рассказываете :)

Comment: ПХПхпхпхпх вирус пишет

Comment: @Frontender, может у вас там ajax? Вы бы код страницы показали чтоли, или кусок кода...

Comment: посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1009096/327441) ответ. В нем есть живой пример для вашего случая.

Comment: Мне ответы напоминают костыли. Постройте приложение через менеджер сообщений. Это вероятно покажется чуть сложнее, однако совершенно очевидно что именно так сейчас работают крупные приложения с фоновыми расчетами и тут даже не идёт речь о каком то определенном языке.

Answer (score 5):

С помощью функции `ignore_user_abort(true)`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: Но... Если у вас разделяемый хостинг, скорее всего есть жесткое ограничение на время выполнения скрипта. Потому таким путём можно лишь ограниченно решить проблему.